# is this the correct xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have written the xml layout for this UI. I was wondering whether it is the right way or not. By right I mean should it be all in one relative layout or separate linear layout horizontal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_repeat"
    android:tileMode="repeat" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp"
        android:paddingLeft="35dp"
        android:paddingRight="35dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:src="@drawable/user" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0.4dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.41"
            android:background="@drawable/username_textbox"
            android:ems="10"
            android:minWidth="110dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:singleLine="true" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:paddingLeft="35dp"
        android:paddingRight="35dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/password_icon" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0.4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/username_textbox"
            android:ems="10"
            android:minWidth="110dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:singleLine="true" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_signin"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="207dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/app_logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Ya it is correct layout. But change width to match_parent of your parent Relative Layout.

Comment: the issue with the way I have written is that the soft keypad does not  pushes the layout top. it appears on the textbox. even though I modified the <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> or <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible"> try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use only one vertical layout .Because all the view are vertically alligned. Image of edit text you can use Drawable{ Left} property in the xml

In XML

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"
```

Or call

```
EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
 text.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check_box), null);
```